# PHP classes and include

Tags: php, oop, class, include

**I have the following question:**

This is my main file `index.php`.

```
<?php

class myClass
{
  function myClass()
  {
    echo '[constructor]';
    $this->myVar = '[i am making a test]';
    $this->A();
  }
  function A()
  {
    echo '[function A works too]';
    echo $this->myVar;
  }
}

$test = new myClass;

?>
```

Now I need to move `function A` into another PHP file `includes/function_a.php` which I could **include_once** in the main file. The reason is to make my main file smaller and easier to read.

What is the best practice of having this done, EXTENDS?

**EDIT:**

I've done this using EXTENDS:

**index.php**

```
<?php

include_once('includes/function_a.php');

class myClass extends anotherClass
{
  function myClass()
  {
    echo '[constructor]';
    $this->myVar = '[i am making a test]';
    $this->A();
  }
}

$test = new myClass;

?>
```

**includes/function_a.php**

```
<?php 
class anotherClass
{
  function A()
  {
    echo '[function A works too]';
    echo $this->myVar;
  }
}
?>
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: So you want `function A` in another file, but still part of the class `myClass`?

Comment: Why splitting something you eventually need to read at once?

Comment: Yes, I want entire function A to be placed in another file, but to have same functionality as if it would be inside the main class.

Comment: You can't "include" a file within a class, unless the include statement itself is actually within a method that exists in that class, and the file will only be included when that method is executed.

Comment: Why don't you instead put the class into a file of it's own? One class per file is quite common in the PHP world. Works well with an autoloader, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hint at the best way to do it at the end of your question. You would need to create a parent class and have your "myClass" extend your parent class. "myClass" would then inherit the methods of the parent class and the parent class could be in another file. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to serve `myClass` as a base class do not `EXTEND` it using another class.

Include the file containing `myClass` class and instantiate an object of `myClass` to use function `A`.

Answer (score 0):

if a function is too long, split it in more small functions. they must be usefull, not like functionA_part01...

eg. getDataFromFile(), if Function A reads out of a file.

if there is still the need to create a new file, you can create an abstract-Class in extends them with myClass.

maybe you should rethink your class design?